# How to get part of a forumla to increase when copied?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using the following formula.  I want the row reference to increase by 1 everytime I drag it to a new row.  Is this possible?

Formula:

=INDEX(Required!$1:$1048576,2,MATCH((CONCATENATE($C$2,$B$2)),Required!$A$1:$J$1,0))

Example:
Row 1:  =INDEX(Required!$1:$1048576,2,MATCH((CONCATENATE($C$2,$B$2)),Required!$A$1:$J$1,0))
Row 2:  =INDEX(Required!$1:$1048576,3,MATCH((CONCATENATE($C$2,$B$2)),Required!$A$1:$J$1,0))
Row 3:  =INDEX(Required!$1:$1048576,4,MATCH((CONCATENATE($C$2,$B$2)),Required!$A$1:$J$1,0))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then use `ROW(2:2)` it will change as it is dragged:

```
=INDEX(Required!$1:$1048576,ROW(2:2),MATCH((CONCATENATE($C$2,$B$2)),Required!$A$1:$J$1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  It worked great!!!  You saved me from changing that row number by hand for thousands of rows. :)